# having a textbox and button horizontally

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, textbox

Is it possible to have a textbox and a button horizontally using JQuery Mobile?

using `data-inline="true"` works for buttons but not when mixed with button and textbox.

data inline [example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html)

`data-type="horizontal"` also didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title></title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#clearMeClearMe").click(function(){
               //$(this).hide();
               $("#clearMe22").val("");
           });
});
</script>
<body> 


<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Textbox Clear Demo</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div id="content">
        <input type="text" id="clearMe22" data-inline="true" name="clearMe22"/>    
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" 
                      data-iconpos="notext" id="clearMeClearMe">Clear</a>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work best for me when I float the button right and restrict the width of the text input:

```
<span>
            <input style="width:90%;display:inline-block" type="text" id="clearMe22" data-inline="true" name="clearMe22" />    
            <a style="float:right" href="#" class="ui-input-clear" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" 
                      data-iconpos="notext" id="clearMeClearMe">Clear</a>
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xeyyr/1/

But someone else might be able to provide a more elegant CSS solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to find a similar solution for a custom button, but in your case I believe you can use the built-in methods for data clear ('data-clear-btn').  You can find this documented here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/textinputs/

and would look like:

```
<input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-3" id="text-3" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: by the time the question was asked there was no build in support from jQuery Mobile. I knew they supported it from 1.3.0 :). +1 for pointing it out here.

Comment: Just looking at that link and not seeing any difference with or without `data-clear-btn` (neither iPhone5/Safari nor Win7/Chrome26).